# hi why this simple snippet code doesnt work?im confused

Tags: javascript

i want to show the paragraph in div

```js
var resultString = "<b>This page \u00A9 Shelley Powers </b>";
// print out to page
var blk = document.getElementById("result");
blk.innerHTML = resultString;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: Looks like it work

Comment: It works for everyone except you, looks like your JS is disabled.

Comment: its in the div onlt

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the guidelines on how to ask a question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. In this case you need to provide a descriptive title ("why this doesn't work" is NOT a good title), and add more details to the question, like what do you expected to see, what actually happened, errors if you got any, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be related to the position of your JS code in your HTML file.

If you add that code, after body tag, it will work because JS can find a reference of your dom `<div id="result"></div>`.

```
<html>
  <body>
  </body>
  <script>
      // your code here
  </script>
</html>
```

If instead you add that javascript at the HEAD of your HTML file,

```
  <html>
<head>
      <script>
          // your code here
      </script>
</head>
      <body>
      </body>   
</html>
```

You need to wait until the document is ready using [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded).

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
  });
```

Working example:

https://jsbin.com/nerarul/edit?html,output

Comment: sorry What's the difference between putting script in head and body?

Comment: @sina Putting script in the head, makes it execute before the elements are loaded, so the script cannot find the elements. It is simply like using a variable **and then defining it**, which should happen in the other way.

Answer (score -1):

check your script tag where you have put javascript code. code is working fine. no problem 
refer w3school for syntax